# Detect if device is charging

Tags: iphone

I can't find anything definite using [my favourite tool](http://www.google.com), however I thought I would put it out here...

Is there a way, using the iPhone SDK, for an app to detect if the device is in a state of receiving power (charging, dock, etc.)?

I would like to be able to disable the idleTimer automatically if the device is receiving power (otherwise it is a user-specified setting).

Comment: Nice touch on linking Google, I laughed.  Good question, saved me time.  Thanks to you and the contributors.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, UIDevice is capable of telling you this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) {
    NSLog(@"Device is charging.");
}
```

See the [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) reference in the docs for more info, and for other values of batteryState.

Answer (score 46):

You are better off using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] != UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged) {
      [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled=YES;
    }
```

This is because you have to concern yourself with 
**two** different states - one is that the battery is *charging*, and the other when it is *fully charged*.

If you *really* wanted to be complete about it - you would register to receive battery monitoring notifications, so you could re-enable the idle timer if the user disconnected main power, etc.

Comment: "You would register to receive battery monitoring notifications": Here's how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31391373/12484

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4**

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

if (UIDevice.current.batteryState != .unplugged) {
    print("Device is charging.")
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true;

if (UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState != .Unplugged) {
    print("Device is charging.");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3:

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
let state = UIDevice.current.batteryState

if state == .charging || state == .full {
    print("Device plugged in.")
}
```

Comment: may be, it is "let state = UIDevice.current.batteryState"

Comment: @BateroBui and everyone that suggested the update; Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [darwin notification center](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter) and use the event name [com.apple.springboard.fullycharged](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SpringBoard.app/Notifications).

This way you will get a notification to your custom method, here is a code snip:

```
// Registering for a specific notification
NSString *notificationName = @"com.apple.springboard.fullycharged";
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                NULL,
                                yourCustomMethod,
                                (__bridge CFStringRef)notificationName,
                                NULL, 
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

---

```
// The custom method that will receive the notification
static void yourCustomMethod(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
  NSString *nameOfNotification = (__bridge NSString*)name;

  if([nameOfNotification isEqualToString:notificationName])
  {
    // Do whatever you want...
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is iOS...you should try the snip code. I used it in a few projects of mine. Also, read the hyperlinks above.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

Bool Value

```
    var batteryState: Bool {
        IDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        let state = UIDevice.current.batteryState

        if state == .charging || state == .full {
            print("Device plugged in.")
            return true

        } else {
            return false
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As many have said, you can detect this state using `UIDevice.current.batteryState`.

but you can go further than this, and see when the state changes using Notification Center.

here's an example for if you want the screen to stay awake when the app is plugged in:

### Swift 5

```
    class BatteryManager {
        static let shared: BatteryManager = .init()

        private init() {
            UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(batteryStateDidChange),
                name: UIDevice.batteryStateDidChangeNotification,
                object: nil
            )
        }
    
        deinit {    
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(
                self,
                name: UIDevice.batteryStateDidChangeNotification,
                object: nil
            )
        }
    
        @objc private func batteryStateDidChange() {
            let state = UIDevice.current.batteryState
    
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = state == .full || state == .charging
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func checkForCharging() {

UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

if UIDevice.current.batteryState != .unplugged {

print("Batery is charging")

} else if UIDevice.current.batteryState == .unplugged {

print("Check the cable")

}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. There are some formatting issues with your post. I generally use markdown and surround my code with three ` characters. (```)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check on more than one place than something like this.

```
class Device {

    static let shared = Device()

    func checkIfOnCharcher() -> Bool {
        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        if (UIDevice.current.batteryState != .unplugged) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if Device.shared.checkIfOnCharcher() == true { 
      //Some Code
} else { 
   // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

... and @Brad's answer for **Swift 5**:

```
    UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    if UIDevice.current.batteryState != .unplugged {
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }
```