# Full list of iOS system notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, system

Is there a list of all system notifications that an app can observe? By "system" notification I mean something like: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.

I'm looking for a way to find out if iOS device was turned off/on. While I doubt that there's a notification which tells exactly that.. I wonder if I could find some alternatives (maybe a combination of system events) that would tell me about device turning off/on.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836142/is-there-a-list-of-notification-names-you-can-use-with-nsnotificationcenter/35410440#35410440