# How to know when the device is charging?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How do I make my iOS app detect when the device is charging?

Answer (score 25):

How about this.

```
UIDeviceBatteryState deviceBatteryState = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState;
if (deviceBatteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging || deviceBatteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateFull) {
    // It is charging
}
```

From the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html),

**`UIDeviceBatteryState:`**
The battery power state of the device.

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown,
   UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged,
   UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging,
   UIDeviceBatteryStateFull,
} UIDeviceBatteryState;
```

**`UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown:`**
The battery state for the device cannot be determined.

**`UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged:`**
The device is not plugged into power; the battery is losing power.

**`UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging:`**
The device is plugged into power and the battery is less than 100% charged.

**`UIDeviceBatteryStateFull:`**
The device is plugged into power and the battery is 100% charged.

---

**Update:**

Just to answer your question completely. Here is how to detect when a charger is plugged in. There is a property named `batteryMonitoringEnabled`.

`batteryMonitoringEnabled:` A Boolean value indicating whether battery monitoring is enabled `(YES)` or not `(NO)`.

Enable battery monitoring if your app needs to be notified of changes to the battery state, or if you want to check the battery charge level.

The default value of this property is `NO`, which:

> - Disables the posting of battery-related notifications
> - Disables the ability to read battery charge level and battery state

This will post the notifications `UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification`, and `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification` when the battery level changes. You can make use of `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification` to detect when the charger is plugged in.

Comment: You'd probably want to update that condition to `if (deviceBatteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging || deviceBatteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateFull )`, since both of those states mean the device is plugged into power.

Comment: @quegal, thanks for correcting, but that was the exact wording from apple documentation which I quoted("the battery is discharging"). :)

Comment: Getting a notification from the system is much more effective: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35340749/4260691