# Calculate battery life on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone: Calculating battery life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469549/iphone-calculating-battery-life)

I would like to know if its possible to calculate the battery lifetime on iOS. So, for how much time I can  use my device until it is 0% of battery percentage.
Thank you all! :)

Comment: Man, that doesn't seem to work. If you know how to help me, I really appreciate that, thanks.

Comment: What's your code like after you added battery monitoring?

Comment: If you want to know how to detect device is charging, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186203/how-to-know-when-the-device-is-charging/13186288#13186288. You cant predict the exact battery lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't.   At least not with any accuracy.

Or, really, you can't unless the user is going to continue doing exactly what they are doing *right now* without any changes in network, signal strength, ambient light, etc... As well, receiving push notifications and/or taking phone calls can impact battery life.  So can media playback, including -- even -- the encoding format used within the media.