# How to find the type of charger connected to iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, power-management

Is it possible to find the `type of charger`(USB Cable,Power Adaptor,wireless car charger ... ) connected to `iPhone` using ios sdk? I would like to find out the charger details connected to a iPhone.

Comment: What are you referring to exactly when you say "type" of charger? Brand? What it's charging from? etc.

Comment: So you want to programatically find what type of charger your iPhone is connected to? I DONT THINK THIS is possible using iOS public APIs. Maybe if you jailbreak your iPhone and install Cydia (or other packages), it could be possible. Would you mind telling what you plan to do with this info? How you are planning to use this?

Comment: No, you wont get those details. You can get the battery state only. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13186203/1730272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible with `ios6 sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the phone is connected to the power source. 
http://www.uinnoblog.com/programmatic-access-to-battery-level-on-the-iphone.html