# Is it possible to find the battery consumption of application in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, power-management

I would like to find out the `battery usage` of an `application` in `iOS`` devices.Is is possible to do this, if it is possible how to estimate the battery usage?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13186203/1730272. You cant find that out. You can only find the device battery state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible directly. You can only query the current battery life. You can't figure out drain from other apps.