# Detect if device is charging or Unplugged

Tags: ios, swift

When I am connecting the device then i can detect, that cable is connected, but when cable unplug that time how will notify that cable is unpluged.

```
if (UIDevice.current.batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.charging)
```

{} else { }
while unpluged method didn't call help me.

Comment: You are looking for this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1620052-uidevicebatterystatedidchange ?

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839279/detect-if-device-is-charging

Comment: Use notification center : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31391418/4733067

Answer (score 0):

```
         UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
         if UIDevice.current.batteryState == .charging {
              print("Device is charging.")
         }
```

Comment: @IBAction func swichButtonChangedStatus (mySwitch : UISwitch) {
        guard mySwitch.isOn else {
            print("Switch is off")
            return
        }
        if (UIDevice.current.batteryState == UIDeviceBatteryState.charging) {
            UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
               
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(detectBatteryChargerUnpluged), name: .UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange, object: nil)
  
        }else {
            print("Please Plug Device.")
        }    
    }