# How to keep updating variable with while loops swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, variables

I'm trying to make a status bar app that reminds me when my mac has reached a charge of 100%. I need to keep updating the charging variable so that I can know when to send the notification. All the `while loops` fail to display my icon on the status bar, and whenever I hover over the empty space it creates, the rainbow spinning wheel is displayed.

I tried to use `didset` but it doesn't show a notification at all.

Note: The problem is not with the notification or the `getbatterystate`, I've used a simple `print` in place of the notification function and nothing displayed either. For the `getbatterystate` I've printed it, and an integer did show up

```
    var charge: Int = Int(getBatteryState())!{
        didSet{
            if charge == 40{
                showNotification()
            }else{
                showNotification()
                charge = Int(getBatteryState())!
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31391418/5133585

Comment: This is not duplicate. Tagged question is for iOS but this question is for macOS.

Comment: @vacawama, Please recheck. you marked it wrong.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. I reopened it.

Comment: An infinite (while) loop is a bad idea. Just use a `Timer` which fires once per second (or even once per 10 seconds is sufficient). In the action (or block) get the battery state and send the notification if necessary.

Comment: @vadian, thanks that helped :)